# Rx.Observable.returnValue how return value after some time?

Tags: rxjs

Rx.Observable.returnValue has scheduler as second parameter. I thought to return value after some time it should be like this

```js
Rx.Observable.returnValue(value, Rx.Scheduler.timeout.scheduleRelative(5000));
```

But second parameter should be just `Rx.Scheduler.timeout` and it makes no sense to me because all schedulers currentThread, immediate or timeout returns value immediately.

So I have two questions:

- How return value after some time?
- Why do we need scheduler parameter in `returnValue` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'd need more time to figure out why the scheduler isn't working for you, you can use the `delay` operator to delay notifications by a certain number of milliseconds.

```
Rx.Observable.returnValue(value).delay(5000);
```

Typically you won't need `Schedulers` in RxJS unless you need very advanced control over when and how notifications are sent. It is more common to need `Schedulers` in Rx.NET.

I believe many schedulers are being removed for the *lite* version of RxJS, simply because they are not typically needed.